# How to declare empty object for subprocess?

Tags: python, subprocess

I need to run shell command from python script. I am using library subprocess. I would like to pack this command to try/except block in case of some error. However I am not able to get information from variable `result` in `except` block, which was written there in `try`. I was trying to declare result object out of try/except block, but I din't find solution which was work. Here is my code

```
import subprocess

result = None

try:
    result = subprocess.run(['lsdkdfk'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(result.stdout)
except Exception as e:
    print(result.stderr) #this doesn't work
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.run` throws a FileNotFoundError and will not return anything if it can't find the command you are trying to use. 'lsdkdfk' is not a valid command and thus `result` is never assigned anything, and there is no stderr to view. You can, however, print the caught exception, if you want.

If it does find the command but the command itself fails, it won't throw an exception unless you specify the argument `check=True`. Now you can also view the stderr.

```py
>>> try:
...   result = subprocess.run(["ls", "asdf"], capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8")
... except FileNotFoundError as e:
...   print("I caught this: ", e)
...
>>> result.stdout
''
>>> result.stderr
"ls: cannot access 'asdf': No such file or directory\n"
>>> try:
...   result = subprocess.run(["invalidcmd", "asdf"], capture_output=True, encoding="utf-8")
... except FileNotFoundError as e:
...   print("I caught this: ", e)
...
I caught this: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'invalidcmd'
```